# What is the process to start developing games for the PS Vita?

Tags: unity

Let's assume a solo/indie developer using Unity and targetting the PS Vita. Let's also assume that the developer's region is Europe.

- What does the developer need to start developing (only developing, not publishing) on the PS Vita?
- Which Unity version/license?
- What needs to be done on the Playstation side? (registration etc)

As an extra point:

- What extra steps are needed for the said developer be able to distribute an alpha/beta version of the game? (for a gamejam and feedback)

Comment: I'm not posting a full answer, because I don't know all of this, but to address the first question 'What does the developer need to start developing (only developing, not publishing) on the PS Vita?' technically you don't need to do anything in order to start developing, since Unity can deploy to different targets at the push of a button. I'm assuming you mean however you want to know how to actually deploy to the device

Comment: Yes, I want to know how to deploy the game to the PS Vita for testing it.

Answer (score 5):

http://blogs.unity3d.com/2014/01/15/playstation-vita-deployment-is-here/

You need Unity 4.3.  You must [register with SCE](https://www.companyregistration.playstation.com/SCEInternetApplications/AreaNewLicensee/MainSystem/CFModules/NewLicensee/snl_master_template.cfm) as a developer to get the proper tools, keys, and so on to be able to publish to the Vita even in testing.  Note that registering with SCE requires (for North American developers):

- Corporate entity (Strongly Recommended)
- A Legal Signatory
- Static IP
- Located in US, Mexico, Central America, South America or Canada

If you need more help on the technical aspects of using Unity to publish to Vita, you should consult Unity's documentation or ask on the Unity or SCE developer forums given how very specific to their technology stacks this question is.

Comment: I took a brief look at SCE Europe's registration form (https://www.companyregistration.playstation.com/SCEInternetApplications/AreaNewLicensee/MainSystem/CFModules/NewLicensee/snl_master_template.cfm?v_which_region=scee&v_which_form=GAME) and looks like it is only for corporations, not for indie developers. Is there any way for a sole developer (non-incorporated) to start developing on the PS Vita?

Comment: @vrinek: you'd have to contact Sony to find out.  The consoles have typically been very unfriendly to indie developers and the "indie revolution" has mostly been limited to the NA console market, unfortunately.  This is partly why the PC game market has come back so strongly in recent years; it's the only fully open/accessible gaming platform.